# Обновление переменной сессии

Tags: php, jquery

Возник вопрос, относящийся к сессиям в php. Создал простейший код выбора города на сайте. Через Ajax отправлю значение города, в файле устанавливаю этот город в переменную сессии и далее через `location.reload()` обновляю страницу. Проблема заключается в том, что переменная сессии при повторном выборе обновляется только если вручную перезагрузить страницу два раза. То есть я выбираю город, страница перезагружается, но значение в сессии остается старым, если я перезагружу страницу еще раз, то значение изменится на то, которое я выбрал ранее. Как можно избежать перезагрузки страницы два раза для изменения значения?

Прикрепляю код ajax запроса:

```
    $('.city-list-item-link').click(function(){
        var city = $(this).html();
        $('.selected-city').html(city);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax.php',
            data: {
                'method': 'city',
                'city': city
            },
            success: function(data){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

Код обработки в php файле:

```
    session_start();
    $method = '';
    if(isset($_POST['method'])){
       $method = $_POST['method'];
    }

    if($method == 'city'){
       $city = '';
       if(isset($_POST['city']) && strlen($city) < 100){
           $city = $_POST['city'];
       }

       $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать с чем связано это поведение, но можно предположить, что страница перезагружается до того, как было установлено значение сессии и при повторной загрузке страницы, значение сессии еще старое. Можно обойтись и без перезагрузки страницы, сделав ajax-запрос, который вернет значение сессии:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/city.php',
        success: function(data){
            ...
        }
    });
```

city.php:

```
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['city'])){
       return $_SESSION['city'];
    }
```